Virtual Reality developer jumps from high-rise building
Period approx. 2006-2018 ... approximate action:
Young adults develop a program for virtual reality. There are negotiations with Asian-looking businessmen. One of the developers (male) jumps from the high-rise building. But the story continues with him. It regularly appears to him a woman (who is getting older). At the end it turns out that it is his girlfriend (she was also there at the negotiations at the time); the girlfriend lives in the real world and had agreed with the businessmen at the time to "keep him" after jumping from the high-rise.

Do you know what country it was made in? Is it English? (US, UK, Aussie) or a foreign film (Asian, European) Were they new actors? or were there any you recognized?

Unfortunately I cannot answer any of your questions. I haven't watched this movie. I am German and I  took over this description from a German "Identify this movie" platform, translated it into English and copied it here.  I am very interested in Science Fiction & Fantasy movies and consider myself to be  an expert of these genres. So I have an own interest that this movie should be identified. Because this is an international platform with many Science Fiction & Fantasy experts, I hope that someone knows the title of this movie.

@BwL - Can you post a link to that forum. It would be interesting to see the actual wording, as well as anything they've already ruled out

@Valorum  Here is the link to the original thread:
https://www.ich-suche-einen-film.de/film/32070/junge-Erwachsene-entwickeln-Programm-zu-virtueller-Welt.html
The German description is basically translated by Google Translate with slight modifications from my side to make the English text more understandable. Currently, there are no suggestions. My attempt to google for the title was not successful.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

I guess you're talking about The Thirteenth Floor from 1999. It had a very similar storyline to what you have described. It's a great movie, I must say.

In late 1990's Los Angeles, Hannon Fuller (Armin Mueller-Stahl) is the owner of a multi-billion dollar computer enterprise and the inventor of a newly completed virtual reality simulation (VR) of 1937 Los Angeles. When Fuller is murdered just as he begins premature testing of the system, his friend and protégé Douglas Hall (Craig Bierko) finds himself the primary suspect, and begins to doubt his own innocence.
Between questioning by LAPD Detective Larry McBain (Dennis Haysbert), Hall meets Jane Fuller (Gretchen Mol), who he is surprised to learn is Fuller's estranged daughter. Hall develops a romance with Jane, who we soon find out is attempting to shut down the new VR system. When a local bartender who witnessed a meeting between Hall and Fuller on the night of the murder is himself found murdered, Hall is imprisoned. He is soon released though, after Jane provides him with an alibi.


Thank you for your answer. I know this movie and I have it on DVD. I have as well thought about it. It is a little bit similar, but it does not match mainly to the description. There are too many mismatches, so I doubt whether this is the movie that are looked for.
"The younger developer team", "jump from a high-rise building" and "negotiations with Asian-looking businessmen" are totally missing in this movie.
Anyway, I will let the questioner in the German forum know about this.
